# How do I assign the value of an XML response node in step 1 to a property in step 2 in soapUI?

Tags: xml, soapui

I have a soapUI test step that creates an object in my database. The XML response I get back contains a node that I need to reference in the next step, namely I need the value after the key 'guid'

```
<flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject serialization="custom">
  <unserializable-parents/>
  <map>
    <default>
      <loadFactor>0.75</loadFactor>
      <threshold>48</threshold>
    </default>
    <int>64</int>
    <int>28</int>
    <string>key</string>
    <boolean>value</boolean>
    <string>key</string>
    <boolean>value</boolean>
    <string>key</string>
    <string>value</string>
    <string>key</string>
    <boolean>value</boolean>
    <string>key</string>
    <null/>
    <string>key</string>
    <null/>
    <string>key</string>
    <null/>
    <string>key</string>
    <null/>
    <string>key</string>
    <null/>
    <string>key</string>
    <null/>
    <string>key</string>
    <boolean>value</boolean>
    <string>key</string>
    <boolean>value</boolean>
    <string>key</string>
    <null/>
    <string>key</string>
    <string>value</string>
    <string>key</string>
    <string>value</string>
    <string>key</string>
    <object-array/>
    <string>key</string>
    <flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject serialization="custom">
      <unserializable-parents/>
      <map>
        <default>
          <loadFactor>0.75</loadFactor>
          <threshold>12</threshold>
        </default>
        <int>16</int>
        <int>3</int>
        <string>key</string>
        <boolean>value</boolean>
        <string>key</string>
        <boolean>value</boolean>
        <string>key</string>
        <boolean>value</boolean>
      </map>
      <flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject>
        <default>
          <inHashCode>false</inHashCode>
          <inToString>false</inToString>
          <namedType>package/class</namedType>
        </default>
      </flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject>
    </flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject>
    <string>key</string>
    <string>value</string>
    <string>key</string>
    <boolean>value</boolean>
    <string>key</string>
    <string>value</string>
    <string>key</string>
    <flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject serialization="custom">
      <unserializable-parents/>
      <map>
        <default>
          <loadFactor>0.75</loadFactor>
          <threshold>12</threshold>
        </default>
        <int>16</int>
        <int>5</int>
        <string>key</string>
        <boolean>value</boolean>
        <string>key</string>
        <boolean>value</boolean>
        <string>key</string>
        <boolean>value</boolean>
        <string>key</string>
        <boolean>value</boolean>
        <string>key</string>
        <boolean>value</boolean>
      </map>
      <flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject>
        <default>
          <inHashCode>false</inHashCode>
          <inToString>false</inToString>
          <namedType>package/class</namedType>
        </default>
      </flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject>
    </flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject>
    <string>guid</string>
    <string>818f40db-c217-46ed-a6a2-7c830d894a95</string>
    <string>key</string>
    <string>value</string>
    <string>key</string>
    <null/>
    <string>key</string>
    <string>value</string>
    <string>key</string>
    <string>value</string>
    <string>key</string>
    <null/>
    <string>key</string>
    <null/>
  </map>
  <flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject>
    <default>
      <inHashCode>false</inHashCode>
      <inToString>false</inToString>
      <namedType>package/class</namedType>
    </default>
  </flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject>
</flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject>
```

I've seen various issues on this topic, but none seem to work for me, I believe due to an error on my part to understand the syntax corretly that soapUI expects.

If test step one is called 'stepOne' and I need to reference the XML response in 'stepTwo',
why does:

def temp = context.expand( '${stepOne#Response//map[1]/string[27]}' );

...not work. I assume I'm referencing the response incorrectly. I would even settle for a way to reference the whole response in the next step. Then I could search through it and find the value I need using groovy.

Should I be attempting a Property transfer instead? If so, source would be stepOne and Response would be ResponseAsXml, target would be stepTwo but I don't really want to assign the whole xml to a property, I'd want to assign JUST the node I need (map[1]/string[27]).

@Sebi- Yeah, I've tried this, I've been through this page countless times. I can transfer the whole response to a TestCase level temporary property, but I can't seem to construct the code to reference this property in the script window correctly...this is what I have now '  def temp = ${#TestCaseName#tempProperty}  ' but this does not work. I would like to bring the whole xml in so I can work with cases where the node I need is not always the 27th "string" in "map". I'm also having trouble declaring the namespace (see xml structure) If you can give an actual example based on the XML I've included for either of these methods, I would be greatful, but I've gotten all I can out of the soapUI tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, us the **Property Transfer TestStep** instead!

> but I don't really want to assign the whole xml to a property, I'd want to assign JUST the node I need

Below the source select boxes you have an input box. There you can write the XPath expression of the node you want to transfer.

You can find a good tutorial here:
http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/transfering-property-values.html

Comment: Ended up using a property transfer for the whole response and searching the values I needed with scripts. A little round about, I know, but hey, whatever works, right?